# In PowerBI, how can I change the granularity of the value shown in the card visualization

Tags: powerbi, report, dashboard, powerbi-embedded

My sum here is 1.62 M, but the card visualization is showing a rounded off figure of 2 M, as shown below. How can I make it show the actual value (1.62 M)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the decimal places under the Format pane for the visual.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Really difficult to find by yourself :)